# Filter user input with filtering date

Tags: php

Since I am using PDO to prevent SQL injection, do I still need to apply PHP's data filters to ensure the input is the correct format? Is PDO protect all kind of injections?

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * from jem WHERE email=? AND pass=? LIMIT 0,1");
```

Any more tip for login script would be help.

Answer (score 1):

Before using PDO, I guess you were validating your data (using a validation filter for instance), and then you escaped it before inserting it in your db. Now, you only need (but still need) to do the first thing.

Regarding your second question, PDO protects you against SQL injections. You still have to escape html before outputting it, to protect from js code injection

Comment: Yes, I would use "HTML Purifier" to remove unrelated HTML and all server side systax.

Comment: But you meant, I will still need to use Filter Data function?

Comment: "Filter Data function" : what is this? A set of functions to validate/sanitize your data? Then yes... A function named filter_data()? I don't know this function. HTML Purifier should be used (PDO does not know anything about HTML, so it cannot handle security risks related to it)